# What part of the damage is halved/doubled for Damage Resistance/Vulnerability?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, damage-resistance

If a creature has "damage resistance" to non-magical weapons how does the final damage number break down?

Is the weapon damage halved only?  Is the total damage (weapon, STR/DEX dmg. bonus) halved?  Would a rogue attacking with a non-magical weapon and using Sneak Attack get the Sneak Attack dmg. halved?

Same question applies to "damage vulnerable" when damage is doubled.

Comment: As a side note, the one thing where you just double the damage is when you get a natural 20.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Actually you just roll 2x as many damage dice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The roll and the appropriate modifier are added together to get total damage.**

> When attacking with a weapon, you add your ability modifier-the same modifier used for the attack roll-to the damage.

Let's say for example, a level 1 rogue with a +1 DEX mod attacks with a dagger(1d4) which does piercing damage. He would add the 1d4 + 1, but he also has *Sneak Attack*.

**If a class feature increases the damage of an attack but doesn't specify a damage type, it is included in the total damage of the attack.**

So, total piercing damage would come out to be 1d4 + 1(DEX) + 1d6(Sneak Attack) and if a creature had resistance/vulnerability to piercing damage that total would be halved/doubled respectively.

**But if a class feature does specify a different damage type, you split the damage types and apply resistance/vulnerability separately.**

Let's say we have a paladin with a +1 STR using a flail(1d8) with *Improved Divine Smite*(1d8).

Total **bludgeoning** damage would come out to 1d8 + 1(STR).

Total **radiant** damage would come out to 1d8.

If the target has resistance/vulnerability to either damage type, the damage of that type is halved/doubled independently of the other.

Answer (score 14):

In each case, you halve or double the total amount of damage of the given type. Since the STR or DEX bonus to damage roll is still adding to the single damage type it is {halved|doubled} along with whatever was rolled.  This applies in just about every case for every individual source of damage.

Any other modifiers are applied first, such as a magical aura that reduces damage within the area. Then resistance is applied, then vulnerability, in the event that both might apply.

> **Damage Resistance:** If a   creature    or  an  object  has resistance to   a  damage   type,   *damage of  that    type    is  halved* against it.
>
> **Damage Vulnerability**: If  a   creature    or  an  object  has vulnerability to    a  damage   type,   *damage of  that    type    is  doubled*    against  it.
>
> Resistance and then    vulnerability   are applied after 
>   all other   modifiers   to  damage. For example,    a   creature    has resistance  to  bludgeoning damage  and is  hit by  an  attack  that    deals   25  bludgeoning damage. The creature    is  also    within  a   magical aura    that    reduces all damage  by  5.  The 25  damage  is  first   reduced by  5   and then    halved, so  the creature    takes   10  damage.
>
> ([D&D 5e SRD](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/SRD-OGL_V1.1.pdf), Pg 97)

Comment: Thanks.  Have always played that way but had a moment of doubt in last session and wanted to get someone's take on it.