# Is the value of "damage dealt/taken" calculated after resistances?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, damage-resistance

The basic rules say about [damage resistance/vulnerability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DamageResistanceandVulnerability):

> Resistance and then vulnerability are applied after all other modifiers to damage. For example, a creature has resistance to bludgeoning damage and is hit by an attack **that deals 25 bludgeoning damage**. The creature is also within a magical aura that reduces all damage by 5. The 25 damage is first reduced by 5 and then halved, so **the creature takes 10 damage**.

The attack deals 25 damage, but the creature took 10 damage. **Can I consider that the attack then dealt only 10 damage?**

This came up with my Wizard, who has [Vampiric Touch](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/vampiric-touch):

> On a hit, the target takes 3d6 necrotic damage, and you regain hit points equal to half the amount of necrotic damage dealt.

and [Life Transference](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/life-transference) (XGtE, p. 160):

> You take 4d8 necrotic damage, and one creature of your choice that you can see within range regains a number of hit points equal to twice the necrotic damage you take.

We wonder what happens when the target has resistance or immunity to Necrotic damage. Is the HP gain calculated after the damage is resisted?

Related questions:

- [Is Resistance/Vulnerability applied before or after Cutting Words?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130573/is-resistance-vulnerability-applied-before-or-after-cutting-words)
- [If someone casts Vampiric Touch on a creature with necrotic absorption, does the caster take damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138115/if-someone-casts-vampiric-touch-on-a-creature-with-necrotic-absorption-does-the)

Comment: Does this answer your question: "[How does Vampiric Touch interact with Resistance/Vulnerability?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70064)". There are two competing answers there, one believes damage taken and dealt are identical, the other, less upvoted one believes that they are different. Here is another questions where the same issue (damage dealt vs damage taken) comes up: "[How much damage can the Guardian of Faith spell deal?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137243)" The less upvoted (but more downvoted) one argues that they are identical.